# Is there a way to analyse single user data in google analytics?

Tags: python, google-analytics, data-science, business-intelligence

I'm trying to analyze (for business intelligence purpose) some google analytics data in python.

All I get after many tutorials are "aggregated" data... like the number of views in a day the thing I need instead is something capable of tracking the behavior of a single user.. like what page of the web site he visited, his bounce rate if he used the e-commerce and so on.

I saw many CSV already prepared for such analysis but I'm starting from scratch with my web site.

Comment: This would violate GPDR In big parts of Europe so depending on where you are this might not even be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the User-ID feature, when you send Analytics an ID and related data from multiple sessions, your reports tell a more unified, holistic story about a user’s relationship with your business:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en

Otherwise, you can examine individual-user behavior at the session level in User Explorer report. The User Explorer report lets you isolate and examine individual rather than aggregate user behavior. Individual user behavior is associated with either Client ID or User ID.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6339208?hl=en